# Bitmap does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Tags: bitmap, xamarin.android

[Error:Bitmap does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvMrg.png)

```
public static Bitmap ByteToImage(byte[] blob)
    {
        using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            mStream.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
            mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream);
                return bm;


        }
    }
```

I need to convert byte[] into bitmap.. but while trying this method i got the above problem on my android project on xamarin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just use:

> BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray (blob, 0, blob.Length);